# Column based on a range in animal dataset- sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Table:

```
num       value      category      name
503       8978       bird          woodpecker
502       7812       animal        
502       7812       animal        
501       7812       animal        
500       7812       animal        panther
499       7812       animal        
498       7812       animal     
467       7812       animal        elephant
```

Within `partition by` of columns `value` and `category`,  output column should be created like below:
When `name` is not null, `output` column takes up the value of `name` and same value to be filled within plus 2 and minus two range of num column.
Example, 500 has `name not null`, 500-2=498 and 500+2=502, within range of 498 to 502, output is filled with `panther`

Output:

```
  num       value      category      name             output
  503       8978       bird          woodpecker       
  502       7812       animal                         panther
  502       7812       animal                         panther
  501       7812       animal                         panther
  500       7812       animal        panther          panther
  499       7812       animal                         panther
  498       7812       animal                         panther
  467       7812       animal        elephant         elephant
```

Comment: A couple additional questions you need to address. Why does 501 and 502 NOT contain 'woodpecker'? They also fall within +/- 2 of a row with name not null. What is the logic behind this selection? What happens when name is not null in 2 or more consecutive num values? What would happen if 1 of the 502 rows contained a not null name but the other did not, or anytime 2 rows differ only in name with one being null?

Comment: Why does 501 and 502 NOT contain 'woodpecker'? ----- `Because it's based on partition by value and category` ,  What happens when name is not null in 2 or more consecutive num values? --- `output would be null`, What would happen if 1 of the 502 rows contained a not null name but the other did not, ----- `output is null when name is not null`, thanks  @Belayer

Comment: pc_pyr, do you try query?

Comment: (1) Why do you have duplicates in the `num` column?  (2) What database are you using?

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `range` window frame:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(name,
                max(name) over (partition by category
                                order by num
                                range between 2 preceding and 2 following
                               )
               ) as imputed_name
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=94f8c1ad6076ad804ed63fd6f4a31282) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

The support for "preceding" and "following" is relatively recent for `range` window frames in Postgres.  In older versions, a lateral join is perhaps the simplest method:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.name, t2.name) as imputed_name
from t left join lateral
     (select t2.name
      from t t2
      where t2.category = t.category and
            t2.name is not null and
            t2.num between t.num - 2 and t.num + 2
      limit 1
     ) t2
     on 1=1
order by num desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9da440c3e9f2e857ea6fbbc3e8f6e411) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: I get an error `Invalid operation: RANGE clause of window functions not yet implemented;`

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, will try it out with your updated query

Answer (score 1):

Try to use window functions with case:

```
select num,value,category,name,output from
(
--if num is in range [match_number-2, match_number+2] then get animal's name
select *, CASE when num>=(match_number-2) and num<=(match_number+2) then max_nam else NULL end as output from
 (
 --find num matching name
 select *,max( case when name=max_nam then num else 0 end )over (partition by value,category) match_number from
  (
  --find name (not null) partition by value,category 
   select *,max(name)over(partition by value,category)max_nam from Table
  )X
 )Y
)Z
```

Comment: @pc_pyr: if that query works for you, then you are most definitely not using Postgres

Comment: There is no `iif` in Postgres

Comment: just changed to case)

Comment: Yes @OlgaRomantsova, it didn't work for me as I m on postgres, will try with your updated answer, thanks.